# Setting CPSR flags directly in ARM assembler

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm doing some testing using ARM assembler (specifically ARM7 little-endian), and I can't find any way of setting the flags/CPSR register without setting them indirectly using an arithmetic instruction.

Is there a way I can write directly to the CPSR flags instead?

Comment: Why do you need to change CPSR? There is probably a way to achieve what you actually need without fiddling with the register directly.

Comment: [Google **setting arm CPSR**](https://www.google.com/#q=setting+arm+cpsr) and [2nd hit is heyrick](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/armwiki/The_Status_register) which has the information.

Comment: There are also many other questions in [the arm tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+cpsr+is%3Aquestion) that have the answer to your question, such as [Accessing banked registers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784978/explicitly-accessing-banked-registers-on-arm).

Comment: @artlessnoise That and the other questions really don't obviously help beginners who just want to set the flags - I was a little suprised to find [we didn't have a good _clear_ duplicate for "how do I set the flags?"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cpsr_f), so now we do.

Comment: @Notlikethat True, the information is not on StackOverflow in an obvious question, but it is in hundreds of other places.

Comment: @artlessnoise As a beginner to this, the documentation gets very confusing very quickly, and I needed a simple answer. But I admit the information was out there.

Answer (score 4):

The [`MSR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0588b/Cihibbbh.html) instruction writes to the PSRs. Note that on an ARM7 it's only available in a privileged mode (the notion of APSR for nonprivileged access to certain CPSR fields came in later architectures).

The ARMv4t reference manual includes this specific example of clearing the flags:

```
MRS R0, CPSR ; Read the CPSR
BIC R0, R0, #0xf0000000 ; Clear the N, Z, C and V bits
MSR CPSR_f, R0 ; update the flag bits in the CPSR
```

Note the read-modify-write operation to preserve reserved bits for the register form. For the specific case of setting flags, writing an immediate value directly to `CPSR_f` is permitted provided you write zeros to the reserved bits.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the MSR and MRS instructions?