# ARM: retrive former "lr" register from a data abort exception handler

Tags: assembly, exception, arm

I'm running FreeRTOS inside a Zynq ARM.
On a ARM system I get an data abort exception. The
exception is raised because of an unaligned address
given to memcpy(). 
I would now like to get the caller of memcpy(). That
is: i would like to retrive the value of "lr" when
within memcpy, before the exception happended. 
I can set a breakpoint to the data exception vector, but when the breakpoint 
hits the "lr" is banked away. Is it possible to 
retrive the "lr" of the usermode bank from within 
abort mode? Maybe with a cp15 coprocessor read?
Thanks Konrad

**Solution**:
Inside FreeRTOS_DataAbortHandler I added a breakpoint and the lines

```
#       define MODE_USR        0x00000010
#       define I_BIT           0x80
#       define F_BIT           0x40 
mrs     r1, cpsr
msr     cpsr_c,  #(MODE_USR|I_BIT|F_BIT)
```

after stepping through the last line I can see the pre-abort stacktrace in XSDK.

Comment: I guess you should try `mrs r0, lr_usr`.

Comment: Assembler doesnt understand that. Im on a Xilinx Zync (ARM-Cortex-A9, a Armv7 i think):

      Error: Banked registers are not available with this architecture. -- `mrs r0,lr_usr'

Comment: In linux I see this macro _store_user_sp_lr_ in arch/arm/kernel/entry-headers.S , maybe I should try it...

Comment: walk the stack which is compiler/programmer dependent possibly

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784978/3156750) pretty much covers it. The `mrs`/`msr` to banked register instructions require the virtualisation extensions, i.e. Cortex-A7/A15 or newer; on Cortex-A9 you're stuck with switching to system mode or bouncing via memory with `stm^`.

Comment: The Cortex-A9 will not support `mrs r1, LR_usr`; `ldm rN, {sp,lr}^` is probably best if in ARM mode.  You can not mode switch back from user mode, but SYSTEM mode (has not banked registers) has access to the user LR.