# ARM Banked register

Tags: arm, cpu-registers

In ARM there is a concept of Banked Register. While reading many questions and their answer and various other resources about what is **Banked** mean here. Then I got this definition:
Register banking refers to providing multiple copies of a register at the same address. Not all registers can be seen at once.

But my query here is that How multiple copies of registers are created. Because we have single register file in our core. And if there is another mode then it will get the new copy of the banked register that will not contain any data and not going to access the data of another mode register.
Then how this copy of register is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Register banking refers to providing multiple copies of a register at the same address. Not all registers can be seen at once.

This is some what correct.  However, the register does not have a 'traditional address'.  The majority of the arm instructions or 'binary encodings' have register as source or destination arguments.  There are sixteen base register so four bits are needed for each register in a binary instruction.  A typical instruction takes 12 bits (out of 32bits) to describe the three registers (two source and one destination).  These bits in the instruction are the 'address' in the definition above.

> But my query here is that How multiple copies of registers are created. Because we have single register file in our core. And if there is another mode then it will get the new copy of the banked register that will not contain any data and not going to access the data of another mode register. Then how this copy of register is created?

They are not 'created' dynamically.  The banked registers are part of the 'register file' of the core and **always exist**.  The issue is that the typical instructions can not access some banked registers unless a 'mode switch' occurs.  This maybe from user to IRQ mode or from normal to secure world with trustzone.

So running the same code in different modes may end up accessing different (banked) registers.  In this way, user code never affects the IRQ stack and vice-versa.  Perhaps more importantly, the IRQ code could corrupt non-banked user registers if careful context saving is not performed at the start and end of an IRQ.

See: [Accessing banked registers on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784978/explicitly-accessing-banked-registers-on-arm) for information on how you might access these different registers.

The newer ARMv7 instruction `mrs r2,sp_svc` breaks this banked register rule and allows access to the banked registers directly without switching a mode.  the intent is to allow context switching code to easily access the banked registers for saving and restoring without a mode switch.

The traditional instruction `ldm rN, {sp,lr}^` allows saving of user stack pointer and link register without switching modes.  Again, this has a special encoding (or addressing as per your definition).

---

Banking is also done with CP15 system registers in trustzone.  [TrustZone monitor mode and banked IFSR...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080918/trustzone-monitor-mode-and-ifar-ifsr-dfar-dfsr) maybe interesting for anyone looking at that ARM 'banking' which is conceptually the same as the register banking.

Comment: Your ans cleared my doubt...i was confused in that register file contains oly 16 registers...

Comment: On behalf of [belwizdadi Med](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11615226/belwizdadi-med): total confusion in explanation : several copies of a register stored at the same address....can you write this sharabia in Assembly so we know which parts are involved and how?

Comment: There is no 'address' per se.  It is a bit range in the binary of the opcode.  Depending on the current mode of the CPU, different 'memory' or register is accessed.  A register is just super fast memory that is physically inside the logic of the CPU.  See the link: [Explicitly accessing banked registers on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784978/explicitly-accessing-banked-registers-on-arm) for some sample code or the TZ link. Also: [Register bank switch at wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_file#Register_bank_switching) which has several translations.

Answer (score 3):

I count 31 registers needed to support the traditional arm.  Several r13s and r14s a bunch for FIQ mode.  First and foremost you are confusing tasks and modes.  At the application level the tasks will all share the same set of registers, there is no banking there, when you switch tasks you have to save registers, the operating system allocates memory for this and for each task switch saves the old tasks registers and restores the next tasks registers.

As far as register banking there are multiple r13s for example.  For each access to the register there is more than a simple offset into the register file it also has other inputs, for example

```
unsigned int get_r13 ( unsigned int mode )
{
switch(mode)
{
case SYS: return r13_sys;
case SVC: return r13_svc;
case ABT: return r13_abt;
case UND: return r13_und;
case IRQ: return r13_irq;
case FIQ: return r13_fiq;
}
}
```

but in logic although the logic could very well look about the same, that or they take the mode bits and logically convert them into some of the address bits into the register file or a combination thereof.

A single register file does not mean there are only 16 registers (r0-r15, not counting cpsr, etc) in the register file, there are 31 or more depending on whether or not it contains *PSR registers.

Comment: But the question is when mode switching happened that mode will get the R13 register which is banked register..okay?? Then what happened to the contents when it was holding previously??

Comment: there are several different registers, which one you access depends on mode, when you return to the prior mode you then have access to the contents of that banked register as the pseudo code above shows.  If you write to r14_svc, some value, then modes switch and you read/write r14_irq for a while, then go back to svc mode you get to acces the r14_svc that was left in that banked register, it doesn tgo anywhere

Comment: I understood what you are saying that data will not be corrupted yes it is true previous mode data will not corrupt but am not able to understand that how the new mode will get the fresh copy of r13 register by architectural way not by coding?

Comment: the bootstrap code or bootloader goes through each mode and sets up the stack, it is software that does it.  For all but user mode you can write to the cpsr to manually change the mode, then you simply write to r13, change mode write to r13, etc.  Possibly one reason why system and user mode share registers.